# Axis of Symmetry for a General Parabola

Tags: conic-sections

> Given a general parabola 
>   $$(Ax+Cy)^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$ 
>   what is the axis of symmetry in the form $ax+by+c=0$?

It is possible of course to first work out the angle of rotation such that $xy$ and $y^2$ terms disappear, in order to get an upright parabola $y=px^2+qx+r$ and proceed from there. This may involve some messy trigonometric manipulations.

Could there be another approach perhaps, considering only quadratic and linear equations?

**Addendum**

From the solution (swapped) by Meet Taraviya and some [graphical testing](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rfrbwcj42x), the equation for the axis of symmetry is

> **Axis of Symmetry**: $$\color{red}{Ax+Cy+\frac {AD+CE}{2(A^2+C^2)}=0}$$

which is quite neat. Note that the result is independent of $F$. Awaiting further details on the derivation.

**Addendum 2**

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711004/what-is-wrong-with-this-method-for-a-rotated-and-shifted-parabola) is an interesting question on MSE on a similar topic.

**Addendum 3** (added 23 May 2018)

> **Tangent at Vertex**:
>   $$Cx-Ay+\frac {(A^2+C^2)(F-k^2)}{CD-AE}=0$$
>   where $k=\frac {AD+CE}{2(A^2+C^2)}$.

Note that the parabola can also be written as

$$\underbrace{Cx-Ay+d}_{\text{Tangent at Vertex if $=0$}}
=m\;\big(\underbrace{Ax+Cy+k}_{\text{Axis of Symmetry if $=0$}}\big)^2$$
where 
$$m=\frac {A^2+C^2}{AE-CD}$$
and $d=\frac {(A^2+C^2)(F-k^2)}{CD-AE}$

See Desmos implementation [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h0pqwroskq).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write the equation as:-
$$(Ax+Cy+t)^2+(D-2At)x+(E-2Ct)y+F-t^2=0$$
Choice of t is made such that $A\cdot(D-2At)+C\cdot(E-2Ct)=0$

$Ax+Cy+t=0$ is the symmetry axis of parabola.

Also, the line $(D-2At)x+(E-2Ct)y+F-t^2=0$ is the tangent at vertex of the parabola.

Explanation :-

Interpret $y^2=4ax$ as:-
$$(Distance \space from \space x=0)^2=4a\cdot (Distance \space from \space y=0)$$

Note that $y=0$ is the symmetry axis of the parabola and $x=0$ is the tangent at vertex. Also, they are perpendicular to each other (This explains why $A\cdot(D-2At)+C\cdot(E-2Ct)=0$ must be true for these lines to be them. This statement is equivalent to $m_1m_2=-1$)This property holds true for a general parabola.

Thus a parabola can be represented as:-

$$(Distance \space from \space L_1)^2=4a\cdot (Distance \space from \space L_2)$$ where $L_1$ and $L_2$ are the symmetry axis and the tangent at vertex of perpendicular.

Comment: Thanks - very nice solution! (+1)