# Find Transverse axis of a Hyperbola

Tags: conic-sections

A hyperbola touches y axis and has its centre at (5/2,20)and one of the focii at (10,24) respectively , find length of the transverse axis. 
well I tried to make set of equations with the general properties of a Hyperbola. But couldn't solve them to get the value of 'a' to get '2a' as length of Transverse axis

Comment: tried to solve the equation to get 'a'

Comment: but couldn't solve it kinda stuck pls help

Comment: I'm 99% sure this is not about _hyperbolic geometry_ -- that doesn't refer to hyperbolas in ordinary plane (or solid) geometry, but a separate kind of geometry with its own rules. Retagging -- please explain further if you re-add the [tag:hyperbolic-geometry] tag.

Comment: well it's an MCQ question and it is from conic sections

Comment: i think i tagged it wrong

Comment: Your way of writing coordinates is strange -- $(\frac52, 20)$ would be a good coordinate pair, but $(\frac{10}{24})$ lacks one of the coordiantes. Do you perhaps mean $(5, 2\frac2{10})$ and $(10,24)$?

Comment: yes typed it wrong

Comment: now can anybody solve it??

Comment: @HenningMakholm retagged it can u help me now??

Comment: @KuvamDevgan Devgan What steps have you written down? Where are you stuck? Please show some effort into writing your question.

Comment: well i am new to stack exchange and don't know much about how u post or ask question here. can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

1. You have the *center*, therefore you actually have *two* foci (and two tangents).
2. Mirroring a focus across a tangent gives a point at distance $2a$ from the other focus.

Comment: can u explain a bit more? what did you mean by two tangents

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2114782/75794).

Comment: the Hyperbola is shifted from origin see the center coordinates

Comment: thanks for helping @ccorn