# Why does taking the derivative of a parabola give the axis of symmetry?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, derivatives

So, I was doing this exercise and it says that to find the axis of symmetry of a general parabola $$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$$ I can just take the partial derivative of this conic.

As I didn't understand why this works, I tried doing the derivative on a normal parabola (the one that has the axis parallel to the x or y axis $$ ax^2+bx+c=0 $$) and it works as well. Can someone explain why this works?

Comment: A [partial derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) can only be performed for a function of two or more variables. I'm assuming the function you are referring to when you say "general parabola" is $y=x^2$. How can you take the partial derivative of this?

Comment: If you mean the derivative of the function, it is $2x$. How can you use this to find the axis of symmetry of $x=0$? Please elaborate on how this method uses the derivative of a quadratic function to find its axis of symmetry.

Comment: Its conic that has the axis of symmetry rotated to an angle, so the equation isn't just the normal equation of a parabola

Comment: Partial derivatives yield tangent vectors.  By setting the tangent vector to zero, you're looking for stationary points.  When the stationary points form a line, you have an axis of symmetry around that line.

Comment: @BlabbotheVerbose But if I have only one point why does it have to be axis of symmetry?

Comment: The question unclear is written, but is a likely duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042028/axis-of-symmetry-for-a-general-parabola).

Comment: I edited once again, it would help if someone would explain why equaling the derivative of $$ ax^2+bx+c=0 $$ to 0 gives me the axis of symmetry

Comment: @NeaguCristian:  I'm pretty sure you want $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ as your vertical parabola.  Please think it through.  The equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ gives a quadratic in $x$ alone, not the equation of a curve.  Implicit differentiation will give you *an* axis of symmetry of the conic.  (Some conics have more than one, e.g. a circle.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that taking the derivative of the parabola at $y=0$ will result in a tangent line at the vertex of the curve. Since the axis of symmetry intersects this line, all you need to do is set $x$ equal to that to get its equation.